# Plumbing Garbage Disposal, Water Filter, Dishwasher and P-Trap

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher, garbage-disposal, filter

I'm doing a new install for a garbage disposal and water filter. Old plumbing didn't line up to new disposal. In total, I have a dishwasher out line (going through the disposal), a waste water line for the water filter (red small hose going to p-trap area and drilled in where you see it connecting), and an exit from my disposal. I'm worried about the slope of the disposal, the connection of filter waste, and the height of p-trap. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: under sink picture]

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like your slope is backwards - the top of the P-trap looks to be higher than the exit point from the disposal. If that's the case then waste water will run into the disposal and sit there instead of draining through the trap and into the sewer. While you won't get sewer gas backing up into the house, you will always have water sitting in the disposal and it will let things grow there and stink.

Comment: I appreciate that, thank you

Comment: Your best bet is to put a level on that horizontal run and double check it. Drain lines should drop 1/4" per foot of run _toward_ the building exit, not back toward the fixture they're draining.

Comment: Thank you. I think my question then is can i lower the p trap and then lower the slope of the run? im concerned about lowering the p trap to lower than the pipe coming out of the wall. Images attached

https://ibb.co/Y7rdk5f
https://ibb.co/5RvV2SG

Comment: Please [edit] to embed your additional pics in the post, just like you did for the first one. Be aware that lowering the trap may mean tearing up the wall to adjust the plumbing in the wall.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you. So putting an elbow out from the wall to lower the p trap wouldnt work?